# Effect of diameter estimate in estimating the norm of traceless second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

The traceless second fundamental form is 
$$
\mathring A = A -\frac{H}{n}g
$$
where $A$ is second fundamental form, $H$ is mean curvature, $g$ is metric, $n$ is dimension, $M_t\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is closed hypersurface. Assume we have 
$$
(1)~~~\int_{M_t} |\mathring A|^2 \le 2\varepsilon   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\
(2)~~~\max_{M_t} |\nabla ^m \mathring A| \le C \varepsilon^\alpha   
~~~~~\forall m\in [1, \hat m]
$$
where $\varepsilon$ is a small constant, $\alpha\in (0,1)$ is constant. And the Topping's estimate about the diameter
$$
(3)~~~diam(M_t) \le C(n) \int _{M_t} |H|^{n-1}~~~~~~~~
$$
There is a conclusion in first paragraph of 8th page in [Blow-up of the mean curvature at the first singular time of the mean curvature flow](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1133.pdf) that 
$$
(1),(2),(3)\Rightarrow \max_{M_t} |\mathring A| \le C_1 \varepsilon^\alpha.
$$
I only get the $\max_{M_t} |\mathring A|$  is bounded from (1) and (2).
I don't how to get the result from (1),(2),(3). Especially how to use the (3).

Comment: If you're allowed to change $\alpha$ then I agree that $(1),(2)$ and an interpolation inequality are enough to get the bound you want. Perhaps the issue is in the dependence of the interpolation constant on the manifold?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  How to do it ?